# Facebook C# SDK + get user's LIKE

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i am using Facebook C# SDK for integration my mvc website with facebook.

I would like to know how to get the list of "LIKEs" for the logged in user. Basically something like "Likes: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=" in the following page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = client.Get("me/likes");
```

Comment: alright, so basically we have to parse json result ourselves right?

Comment: `result` should be a JsonObject object

Comment: Remember to add the permissions in order to get the likes